# read phone state not working android marshmallow even permission granted and receiver is add also permission granted run time (receiver not calling)

Tags: android

This is my Manifest receiver and permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: <receiver  android:name=".receiver.MainReceiver">
            <intent-filter  android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Do you ask for permissions during runtime?

Comment: My code work on below M and also on N but not on M

Comment: Yes, I ask for permissions during runtime

Comment: show your code for run time permissions

Comment: public static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};

Comment: public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for(String permission : permissions) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: I also grant permission on phone settings.

Comment: Did you override onRequestPermissionsResult() method?

Comment: yes I override onRequestPermissionsResult() method

Comment: There is some error/crash, or it's just simply not working?

Comment: No any error/crash It working on android Nougat  and below marshmallow but not working on marshmallow.

Comment: My Broadcast receiver not calling in case of marshmallow

Comment: May you show a little more code of yours for better understanding?

Comment: public class MainReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    String incommingNumber;
    String incno1 = "9041776833";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (null == bundle)
            return;

Comment: onReceiver() not calling during incoming call.............

Comment: did you have any success ?